# How to test a delayed event handler with requestAnimationFrame in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've got a function that should be get executed in near future and I want to test it with jest but have no idea how to do this properly. Actually, I'm using **React + testing react library** but that doesn't change anything I suppose.

**Here's the function itself:**

```
let start;
const holdClick = (el, delayedClickHandler, time = 0) => {
  if (time === 0) return delayedClickHandler();
  let counter = 0;
  function countToExecute() {
    if (counter === time) delayedClickHandler();
    else {
      start = requestAnimationFrame(countToExecute);
      counter += 1;
    }
  }

  start = window.requestAnimationFrame(countToExecute);

  el.ontouchend = () => {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(start);
  };
};
```

**My Component**

```
function Component() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <span
      // data attribute must be changed to "active" after 30 ticks
      data-testid={clicked ? 'active' : 'static'}
      onTouchStart={e => holdClick(e.target, () => setClicked(true), 30)}
    >
      click me
    </span>
  );
}
```

**And my test**

```
test('execute delayed click', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(window, 'requestAnimationFrame').mockImplementation(cb => cb());
  });

  const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);
  const el = getByTestId('static');

  fireEvent.click(el);

  jest.useFakeTimers();
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(el).toHaveAttribute('data-testid', 'active');
  }, 10000);
  jest.runAllTimers();
});
```

---

My guess is that the problem lays in `requestAnimationFrame` but as I've mentioned before, I'm pretty much clueless of any ways to fix this. I've tried to add `jest.spyOn(window, 'requestAnimationFrame').mockImplementation(cb => cb());` but it didn't change anything. **So** I'm wondering if there's a solution that doesn't require a troublesome mock of `window` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your callback is set on the `onTouchStart` prop, meaning you'll need to fire the `touchStart` event in order to trigger it.

```js
fireEvent.touchStart(el);
```

Second, in your `countToExecute` function the `counter` variable should be increased *before* the `requestAnimationFrame` call, otherwise `counter` will never get to increase. This is because the actual `requestAnimationFrame` calls its callback on each repaint (each "tick"), but since it's mocked in the tests the callback gets called immediately.

```js
function countToExecute() {
    if (counter === time) {
        delayedClickHandler();
    } else {
      counter += 1;
      start = requestAnimationFrame(countToExecute);
    }
}
```

Your test should then look like the following:

```js
test('execute delayed click', () => {
    jest.spyOn(window, 'requestAnimationFrame').mockImplementation(cb => cb());
    const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />);
    const el = getByTestId('static');
    fireEvent.touchStart(el);
    expect(el).toHaveAttribute('data-testid', 'active');
});
```

Comment: Oh I've forgotten to refactor and change click on touch. Your code has actually worked for me but honestly speaking, I don't get why increasing counter before animation request makes this difference. That code works perfectly in browser and `counter` does get increased, so what happens in the **Node** environment? Shouldn't this mock return `countToExecute` function with updated `counter` in scope? I mean it must be increased anyway, mustn't it?

Comment: The original `requestAnimationFrame` calls its callback on each repaint (each "tick"), but in the tests it's called immediately since we're mocking it. Making this change shouldn't affect the actual behaviour, and logically makes sense too since you want to ensure `counter` has been increased before `countToExecute` gets executed again.

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I was thinking about. Thank you for a clear explanation!